# What are some decent IDEs that i can use to code python?

Tags: python, open-source, ide

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What IDE to use for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python)

I really don't like the python gui, so im looking for an IDE to use. Open source.

Comment: duplicate of [What IDE to use for Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python)

Comment: Please search before you post a question. This has already been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest bluefish. It's a very powerful IDE that i've used a lot and i definately suggest it.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Wing](http://www.wingware.com/) in the past. I like it.

Comment: i was looking for open source. wing trial has that annoying 10 minute thing. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use NetBeans with Python plugin. I like it because it integrates well with several Python versions I have installed, and it has some cool features (like unlocking a window so it looks more or less like Python's IDLE).

Comment: thanks. i tried that one but i didn't like.